# angular-cli: Can't export directive MyComponent as it was neither declared nor imported

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I run

```
npm run build --prod
```

I get the error

```
ERROR in : Can't export directive CandlestickAndVolumeComponent in 
C:/ClientApp/src/app/components/charts/candlestick-and-volume/candlestick-and-volume.component.ts 
from BackdataJobDetailDashboardModule in 
C:/ClientApp/src/app/dashboards/BackData/backdata-job-detail-dashboard/backdata-job-detail-dashboard.module.ts 
as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

When I run

```
npm start
```

everything works just fine

Although the error message is clear I cannot work out how to correct it as I am a little new to angular-cli

here is my backdata-job-detail-dashboard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CandlestickAndVolumeComponent } from '@app/components/charts/candlestick-and-volume/candlestick-and-volume.component';
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
import stock from 'highcharts/modules/stock.src';
import more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';
import { BackdataJobDetailDashboardRoutingModule } from './backdata-job-detail-dashboard-routing.module';

export function highchartsModules() {
  // apply Highcharts Modules to this array
  return [stock, more];
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [CommonModule, BackdataJobDetailDashboardRoutingModule, ChartModule],
  exports: [CandlestickAndVolumeComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES, useFactory: highchartsModules } // add as factory to your providers
  ]
})
export class BackdataJobDetailDashboardModule {}
```

Here is my candlestick-and-volume.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StockChart } from 'angular-highcharts';
import { ApiService } from '@app/services/snakeApi/api.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ChartDataCandleStick, ChartDataIndicator } from '@app/model/ChartData';
import { Options } from 'highcharts/highstock';
import { WorkFlow } from '@app/model/WorkFlows/WorkFlow';
import { TradingDataService } from '@app/services/Data/trading-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candlestick-and-volume',
  templateUrl: './candlestick-and-volume.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candlestick-and-volume.component.scss']
})
export class CandlestickAndVolumeComponent implements OnInit {
...
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You just forgot to add `CandlestickAndVolumeComponent` in `@NgModule#declarations` section :)

Comment: ohh yes. I see. It is working now. Thank you very much